# do not show the component if the key has certain element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oop

i have a dictionary where it has keys and data associated with the key as shown below.Dont show the span for key in which **Total** value is present. i mean if the value is present in values associated to key the component should be hidden else should be visible
**this is in vue** so inshort span should only display **color** as its not having Total value in it as shown in data. below code is what i have tried till now
Below data is dummy data it should be dynamic, values and key will be changing.

```
data:{
  name: ["0-10","10-20","100+","Total"],
  age: [ "70-80","80-90","90-100","Total"]
  color:["red","green"]
}

<span
          v-for="(elements, index) in Object.keys(data)"
          :key="index"
          >
          <span
            v-if="
              Object.values(data.elements).includes('Total')
            "
          ></span>
          <span
            v-else
            :title="elements"
          >
            {{ elements }}
          </span>
```

was trying with function as show below

```
preprocessing() {
      var keyss = Object.keys(this.data);
      for (var i of keyss) {
        console.log(i);
        if (this.data.i.filter((e) => e !== "Total")) {
          keyss.pop(i);
        }
      }
      return keyss;
    },
```

this is the edited version and its work for my scenario

```
data:{
  name: ["0-10","10-20","100+","Total"],
  age: [ "70-80","80-90","90-100","Total"]
  color:["red","green"]
}
<span
          v-for="(elements, index) in Object.keys(data)"
          :key="index"
          >
          <span
            v-if="
              !Object.values(data.elements).includes('Total')
            "
:title="elements"
          >{{ elements }}</span>
          </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `elements` is holding the key you have to use `[]` notation to read dynamic properties

```
Object.values(data[elements]).includes('Total')
```

Otherwise you can rewrite your template like below

```
<span v-for="(value, key) in data">
  <span v-if="value.includes('Total')" ></span>
  <span v-else :title="key">{{ key }}</span>
</span>
```

Comment: The first inline worked for me. Thank you
```<span v-for="(value, key) in data">
  <span v-if="!value.includes('Total')" title="key">{{ key }}</span>
</span> ```   Even this resolves my issue